# How can we write this in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

```
<a href=# alt=Image Tooltip rel=tooltip content="<div id=imagcon>
   <img src='.$row['images'].' class=tooltip-image/></div><div id=con>Address:'.$row['Address'].'</div>
<div id=con>Contact:'.$row['contact'].'</div>
<div id=con>Email:'.$row['email'].'</div>
<div id=con>Status:'.$row['status'].'</div>
<div id=con>Age:'.$row['age'].'</div>">'.$row['Name'].'</a>
```

How can we write this in cakephp?

Comment: Care to format your code?

Comment: This is really terrible code.  I don't even...  I tried to edit it to format it but it's like a mash-up of HTML and PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are asking because you know you *should* be using the CakePHP HTML helper for links but in your case I wouldn't - I would either write a custom CakePHP Helper to display your HTML .. if you are going to be using this code again and again, build a helper (link on how to do this below)..

... but looking at what you have there, you are not actually doing too much, the link doesn't actually go anywhere so why not keep what you have? With the exception of the image helper to be safe:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image($row['images'], array('class'=>'tooltip-image'));?>
```

Using a frameworks Helpers can save a serious amount of time and solve some problems with locations too, but are not always the solution.. you can over-engineer the use of a helper.

Here's all the information you need in CakePHP for Helpers, so's you how to use existing helpers and how to create your own: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code is invalid. you can not have more than one id with the same value. Without fixing your broken html

```
$content = '<div id=imagcon>' . $this->Html->image($row['images'], array('class' => 'tooltip-image')) . '</div>' . 
    '<div id=con>Address:'.$row['Address'].'</div>' . 
    '<div id=con>Contact:'.$row['contact'].'</div>' . 
    '<div id=con>Email:'.$row['email'].'</div>' . 
    '<div id=con>Status:'.$row['status'].'</div>' . 
    '<div id=con>Age:'.$row['age'].'</div>';

echo $this->Html->link($row['name'], '#', array(
    'alt' => 'image',
    'rel' => 'tooltip',
    'content' => $content,
    'escape' => false
)) . '<br/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things wrong with the basic HTML of your code, before even throwing the PHP into the mix.

- Attributes should have `" "` quotes around the values.
- If you are going to put HTML inside another HTML tag's attribute, it should be escaped.
- Unless the entire string is PHP, you need to inject PHP with `<?php  ?>` tags.
- Your HTML tags use the same ID many times.  IDs should really be unique on the page, so if you find yourself reusing an ID a lot, make it a class instead.
- I don't think `content` is a valid attribute for an HTML anchor (if it is, ignore this point).  Custom attributes should ideally be prefixed with `data-`, so in this case the attribute would be `data-content`.

The first thing you should do is separate out the content part into its own PHP variable that you can add to the link.  This will help with code readability and organisation a lot.

**Fixed PHP without changing your HTML attributes**

```
<?php
    $content = '<div id="imagcon">
                    <img src="' . $row['images'] . '" class="tooltip-image" />
                </div>
                <div id="con">Address:' . $row['Address'] . '</div>
                <div id="con">Contact:' . $row['contact'] . '</div>
                <div id="con">Email:' . $row['email'] . '</div>
                <div id="con">Status:' . $row['status'] . '</div>
                <div id="con">Age:' . $row['age'] . '</div>';

    echo '<a href="#" alt="Image Tooltip" rel="tooltip" content="' . $content . '">' . $row['Name'] . '</a><br />';
?>
```

**Although I would recommend you change your HTML content to this, if you can:**

It uses classes instead of repeated IDs, and also has an outer div wrapper with a unique ID so that you can effectively target the inner elements from your CSS or JavaScript. If your database table doesn't have an `id` column, replace with the name of your primary key field, or a counter in the loop if you don't have a primary key (you should). I have added this because it looks like you are looping through rows and outputting these links. If you aren't you could remove the outer div. Finally, I have changed the link's `content` attribute to `data-content` instead.

```
<?php
    $content = '<div id="row-' . $row['id'] . '">
                    <div class="imagcon">
                        <img src="' . $row['images'] . '" class="tooltip-image" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="con">Address:' . $row['Address'] . '</div>
                    <div class="con">Contact:' . $row['contact'] . '</div>
                    <div class="con">Email:' . $row['email'] . '</div>
                    <div class="con">Status:' . $row['status'] . '</div>
                    <div class="con">Age:' . $row['age'] . '</div>
                </div>';
?>
```

**CakePHP equivalent**

```
<?php
    $content = '<div id="row-' . $row['id'] . '">
                    <div class="imagcon">' . $this->Html->image($row['images'], array('class' => 'tooltip-image')) . '</div>
                    <div class="con">Address:' . $row['Address'] . '</div>
                    <div class="con">Contact:' . $row['contact'] . '</div>
                    <div class="con">Email:' . $row['email'] . '</div>
                    <div class="con">Status:' . $row['status'] . '</div>
                    <div class="con">Age:' . $row['age'] . '</div>
                </div>';

    echo $this->Html->link($row['name'], '#', array(
        'alt' => 'Image Tooltip',
        'data-content' => $content,
        'rel' => 'tooltip'
    ));
    echo '<br />';
?>
```